# Why am I receiving this error when querying data from quandl, yahoo or google finance?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quandl, pandas-datareader

Whenever I run the below script I receive an error (also below) that says it is unable to read the URL for the quandl site. However, I find this strange because it says the same thing if I use `web.DataReader('AAPL', 'google', start, end)`, for example, or even the `get_data_yahoo()` method. In fact, sometimes it will work if I am only trying to get the prices of one stock, but I will usually have to run it multiple times before it actually works.

Is this an known problem with `pandas_datareader` or is it something I am doing/not doing?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd

start = dt(2017, 1, 1)
end = dt.now()

df1 = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'quandl', start, end)
df2 = web.DataReader('JPM', 'quandl', start, end)
df3 = web.DataReader('JNJ', 'quandl', start, end)
df4 = web.DataReader('PG', 'quandl', start, end)
df5 = web.DataReader('XOM', 'quandl', start, end)
df6 = web.DataReader('VZ', 'quandl', start, end)
df7 = web.DataReader('IEF', 'quandl', start, end)
df8 = web.DataReader('SPY', 'quandl', start, end)
```

***Error Output***:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    df7 = web.DataReader('IEF', 'quandl', start, end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 172, in DataReader
    session=session).read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/quandl.py", line 105, in read
    df = super(QuandlReader, self).read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 181, in read
    params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 79, in _read_one_data
    out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 90, in _read_url_as_StringIO
    response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 139, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/IEF.csv?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-11-25&order=asc`

EDIT: I make requests maybe once every 5 minutes while I'm backtesting the script.

EDIT2: The same script now works if I change the query to `google` instead of `quandl`, so maybe quandl is having problems currently?

Comment: How frequently are you making this requests? All at once, hundreds of times a day etc... Could it possibly be you're being rate limited? Or maybe a glitch in the connection or the server's just busy right now... etc... If it works now and then - it's not likely to be an issue with the module - just the connection and server.

Comment: @Jon Clements Maybe once every 5-10 minutes, but today, just before posting I hadn't made a request since last night and it still threw the error

Comment: Can you access the page it refers to by your browser without issue?

Comment: @Jon Clements No I cannot, `This site can’t be reached

The web page at https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/IEF.csv?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-11-25&order=asc might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`